# Controlling LabVIEW front panel from python returns typeerror nonetype object is not callable

Tags: python, win32com, labview

Using code below where vi_path is .vi file path, control_name and ind_name are control name and indicator name strings

```
labview = win32com.client.Dispatch("Labview.Application")
VI = labview.getvireference(vi_path)
print(f'Name: {VI.Name}')
VI.setcontrolvalue(control_name,f) # this works to set float values
s=(VI.getcontrolvalue(ind_name))
```

works fine. But

VI.Run() #async = False default i.e wait for exec to finish

is creating the TypeError:NoneType object is not callable error

Comment: I would recommend you check out TestScript from genuen: https://www.genuen.com/products/testscript. It's a fully bidirectional LabVIEW/Python connector that abstracts away all the tcp/ip connection. It's free and source-released.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this line added in a code sample elsewhere  VI._FlagAsMethod('Run')
before using VI.Run()
This fixed the problem. Apparently some of the active x methods in LabVIEW are not getting recognized properly- odd since getcontrolvalue and setcontrolvalue methods dont need to be flagged as methods but Run method does. Anyway, recommend using _FlagAsMethod before using any methods that are generating this TypeError Nonetype object not callable error as well.

Comment: Also note that VI.Call() i.e call without passing parameters will run the VI with default values so setcontrolvalue , followed by VI.Run() works as expected but setcontrolvalue followed by VI.Call() will ignore the previously set value and run VI with default values.